# What Python RegEx can I use to indicate a pattern only in the end of an Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, regex

I am working with a dataset where I am separating the contents of one Excel column into 3 separate columns. A mock version of the data is as follows:

| Movie Titles/Category/Rating |
| --- |
| Wolf of Wall Street A-13 x 9 |
| Django Unchained IMDB x 8 |
| The EXPL Haunted House FEAR x 7 |
| Silver Lining DC-23 x 8 |

This is what I want the results to look like:

| Title | Category | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wolf of Wall Street | A-13 | 9 |
| Django Unchained | IMDB | 8 |
| The EXPL Haunted House | FEAR | 7 |
| Silver Lining | DC-23 | 8 |

Here is the RegEx I used to successfully separate the cells:
For Rating, this RegEx worked:

```
data = [[Movie Titles/Category/Rating, Rating]] = data['Movie Titles/Category/Rating'].str.split(' x ', expand = True)
```

However, to separate Category from movie titles, this RegEx doesn't work:

```
data['Category']=data['Movie Titles/Category/Rating'].str.extract('((\s[A-Z]{1,2}-\d{1,2})|(\s[A-Z]{4}$))', expand = True)
```

Since the uppercase letter pattern is present in the middle of the third cell as well (EXPL and I only want to separate FEAR into a separate column), the regex pattern '\s[A-Z]{4}$' is not working. Is there a way to indicate in the RegEx pattern that I only want the uppercase text in the end of the table cell to separate (FEAR) and not the middle (EXPL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie Titles/Category/Rating':['Wolf of Wall Street A-13 x 9','Django Unchained IMDB x 8','The EXPL Haunted House FEAR x 7','Silver Lining DC-23 x 8']})

df2 = df['Movie Titles/Category/Rating'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Movie>.*?)\s+(?P<Category>\S+)\s+x\s+(?P<Rating>\d+)$', expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/in9Dcj/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<Movie>.*?)` - Group (Column) "Movie": any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Category>\S+)` - Group "Category": one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+x\s+` - `x` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Rating>\d+)` - Group "Rating": one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is always `x` between Category and Rating, and the Category has no spaces in it, then the following should get what you want:

```
(.*) (.*) x (\d+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
'((\s[A-Z]{1,2}-\d{1,2})|(\s[A-Z]{4})) x'
```

would work for you - to indicate that you want the part of the string that comes right before the `x`. (Assuming that pattern is always true for your data.)